# Can Java do this?

Tags: java, applet, icc

I need to write a Java web applet (if this can't be done via web applet can it be done another way?)

It's been a long long time since I've touched Java so sorry if my terminology is wrong, I'm going to have to relearn it, but before I invest serious time in it I want to know if what I am aiming to achieve is possible.

I need to be able to:

- Access ICC profile on users computer
- Read ICC profile data
- Utilize an SDK for some specialist hardware

Can Java do this?

Comment: ICC is a common acronym, what are you referring to?

Comment: @karianna - "ICC" is ambigious but [ICC profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile) isn't

Comment: @Andreas_D Internet Chess Club profile is something I've had to deal with in the past :-)

Comment: @karianna - oh... that's something new. Does it have a public API? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A signed applet can have full system access after being installed and complete almost any task.

Comment: +1 for the signed Applet part (which I added to my answer as well)

Answer (score 3):

In short you can use Java to do just about anything (especially with a signed Applet, if you want to use Applets that is), it gets easier if the third party entities you're dealing with have a Java API you can utilise or a std way to interact with them (web servicesm, RDMS et al).

You can call out to native SDKs using JNI as well.  I assume you can access this ICC Profile via the SDK call?

But overall should you use Java in this case?  I'd need to see answers to my questions first :-)

Comment: It has to be multi platform for Mac and Windows, I've looked at Air but it can't do what I need it to apparently

Comment: How do you access the ICC Profile?  Through an SDK?